# quizgame randomize getting duplicates in production

Tags: django, random, django-rest-framework

one way that'd probably work "well enough" is (assuming you can afford to do a count): pick a random indexed column to order by. Order the whole queryset by that. Pick a range between the top and the bottom of the resultset (eg: 1234:1254) and take 1 random result from there. At 50K rows it's ~*probably*~ a blip in terms of query time (though tbh so might rand() be, at that), however I am trying to translate it into my own codebase as far as I am creating the poc for production code, and I know `order_by("?")` will kill my db

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def questions_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        questions = Question.objects.all().order_by('?').first()
        serializer = QuestionListPageSerializer(questions)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: hi, what is the question?

Comment: the question is mostly, how to avoid getting duplicates , but without kill the db using `order_by("?")`

Comment: what do you mean by getting duplicates?

Comment: RAND(), from `order_by` django it gets duplicates the same number or obj

Comment: Are your users authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

This may be more cost-efficient:

```
import random
question = Question.objects.all()[random.randint(0, Question.objects.all().count()-1)]
```

Comment: what about the duplicates?

Comment: can you please make a full sentence about what you mean by "duplicates". like: "I don't want the same question to be asked to same user." or "I don't want the same question to be asked ever" or "I wanna delete the question which is already asked".

Comment: I mean with duplicates the way to getting repeating values(questions) twice

Comment: I really cannot get why are you so stingy with words :) so do you have any login system or do you somehow store any data from the people who answers questions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep the questions that users answered and the answer to it. assume that the model is called AnsweredQuestion and it has fk to both user and question. you should just get random questions between the question that is not in relation with user in AnsweredQuestion.